# what is the difference between $object::$variable and $object->variable

Tags: php, class

what is the difference between **$object::$variable** and **$object->variable**

both of them can be used to achieve the same but creates difference when the class member-variable is static as follows-

***$object::$variable*** :- This syntax allows the static variable to be achieved through the object

But

***$object->variable*** :- This syntax does not allow the static variable to be achieved through the object.

What is the semantic difference between the two?

Comment: A static property can be accessed without actual instance of the object

Comment: Instance properties vs. class properties. Two very different things. Read more about them.

Comment: Did you read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)?

Answer (score 2):

`$object::$variable and $object->variable`

above both are are valid for accessing class property.

Only difference is that `$object::$variable` is used for access static property where as `$object->variable` is used for accessing property of class from instance.

For more words refer **Amal Murali** commented question link.

Answer (score 0):

With $object::$variable you refer to the $variable of the class, $object->variable refers to the $variable of a instance of this class.